# AngularJS $routeProvider not redirecting after link to /

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I have a fairly simple routing situation, but I can't get it to work. The banner at the top of the page to has a link to '/', I expect this to take the user to the top level of my AngularJS app, but it doesn't. It takes me to some intermediate, and broken page. If I then reload that page, it does the redirection.

Here is my route setup:

```
$routeProvider.when('/',
            {
                templateUrl : 'partials/landing.html',
                controller : 'DataController',
                title : appTitle + baseDelimiter + ' Home'
            }   
        )
//other unrelated routes clipped out for brevity
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })
```

I believe it is not being redirected because I have the following code in app.js and it only gets called once when the user clicks on any '/' link (I see the url in the window change to http://localhost/#)

```
niwaDataApp.run(['$rootScope', '$route', function($rootScope, $route) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (oldVal !== newVal) {
            document.title = $route.current.title;
        }
    });
}]);
```

When it is run `$route.current.redirectTo` is "/", and then I'm left with a great big Angular sized hole in my page. If I reload it , the code gets called twice, the first time the $route is the same as before, then it has all the details of the proper '/' route above, the url changes to http://localhost/#/ and the page fills in properly.

So why doesn't `<a href="/">Click me</a>` get the user to the proper route, whilst reloading from the bad url does?

Comment: Have you tried `<a href="#/">Click me</a>`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use an a-href link and use the fragment routing, you need to make an appropriate link as well, f.e.:

`<a href="#/">Click me</a>`

Comment: I haven't tried that and I'd prefer not to. The header that has that link is common across all our web apps and not all of them are Angular based. Plus I know href="/" works on another AngularJS app, the only difference there is that '/' also does a redirect to another route.

Comment: I assume that something goes wrong with the initialization of the application, hence it works when reloading the page. That is why I suggested to not leave the angular app. Have a look at the console if there are any error messages displayed.

Comment: Check if you register any other javascript hooks and/or scripts like analytics software to isolate the problem.